# What do you call a symbol "—||—" for repeating something that has already been written? Does it have a name at all?

Tags: punctuation, symbols

For example, it's used like that:

IEC 61508 Functional Safety of Electrical/Electronic safety-related systems — Part 2. Requirements for ...

—||— Part 3. Glossary

Or, to be precise, this is how it goes:
[image: This is how I spotted this symbol]

Comment: I'd say it's just a somewhat florid / ornate (non-standard? idiosyncratic?) [**ditto mark**](https://grammarist.com/interesting-words/ditto-and-ditto-mark/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Using a simple double-quote (") is standard in most English-speaking countries; the form given here, with horizontal lines on either side of the (somewhat drawn-out) double-quote, is standard in several other countries/languages. Although the usage here seems rather odd to me – I wouldn’t expect a ditto mark to be used at all in what looks like a printed table of contents.

Comment: The horizontal bar simply indicates that the ditto applies to everything above the bar, rather than everything directly above the double-quote.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I meant "non-standard" *in the specific context*. I assume we only actually use double-quote because it's been available as a "standard" character in most Western character sets since we invented printing -> typewriters -> computer fonts, though it's not uncommon to see variants such as a couple of slashes (**//**). But normally we only use this "orthographic device" in the context of *data presented in tabular format*, where the "non-explicitly repeated" text is somewhere *directly above* the relevant ditto mark(s).

Comment: @Fumble My comment was just to note that it’s not necessarily idiosyncratic, just (likely) transferred from someone’s first language, so it’s non-standard in English, but probably not where it was transferred from. Also, I was really thinking more about handwriting here – most English-language handwritten documents that use ditto marks do use just two vertical/slanted little strokes, whereas in many other locations, the handwritten form is two vertical strokes flanked by two horizontal strokes. (Also _do._, which is used both in English and elsewhere, although not my many people anymore.)

Comment: I've never seen this before. Wikipedia's article on the ditto mark, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark, claims (without attribution) that this construction is used in Greek.

Comment: The IEC Central Office & IECEE/IECRE Secretariat are in Geneva, with an additional Secretariat in Australia and four other regional offices around the globe. I'm curious, for instance, if this way of indicating "ditto" is used commonly in Switzerland. As an editor of American English, I have never encountered the use of "—||—", even in academic works. I suspect Fumble and Janus are both correct.

Comment: This is one instance where an actual picture (rather than using Markdown and ELU's fonts to reproduce it) would be really helpful.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Done!

Comment: How quaint! I don’t believe I’ve ever seen that used in print (much less, as seems to be the case here, in digital form). It’s always been an exclusively handwritten thing in my experience, regardless of the exact shape.

Answer (score 4):

FumbleFingers commented:

> I'd say it's just a somewhat florid / ornate (non-standard? idiosyncratic?) [**ditto mark.**](https://grammarist.com/interesting-words/ditto-and-ditto-mark/)

Comment: | | cannot be a "ditto mark". Most likely the word ditto would be used.  Your link even says: A ditto mark (or ditto sign) is a symbol (“) which signifies ditto. This (“) is a ditto mark, not | |.

Comment: *Pace* Lambie, I’d say it fairly clearly **is** an elaborated notation constructed around an enlarged ditto mark. I do read the || as an enlarged ditto mark. Or anyway as a newly invented compound inspired by and transparently modeled after the canonical ditto mark, ″.

Answer (score 2):

As Fumblefingers noted, this is a form of ditto mark.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark) notes that the form -----"----- is used in Russian, Swedish, and Norwegian.
Also, [some extension of Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53823/is-there-a-ditto-symbol) can do these

> [image: ditto]